# Okta: Where can I find SSO Url and Audience URI as a tenant admin?

Tags: saml-2.0, okta

here's my following setup, I have 2 Okta tenants:

- Okta Tenant A (identity provider)
- Okta Tenant B (service provider)
  I would like to create an Okta application in Tenant B that supports SSO for users in Tenant A through SAML.

The setup in Tenant A seems straightforward:

Classic UI > Applications > Create a New Application Integration > Web SAML 2.0

The form request the following fields:

- Single sign on URL
- Audience URI (SP Entity ID) 
  Both of those values should come from the service provider (Okta application in Tenant B) but I can't seem to find in which admin page they are displayed in Tenant B.

Moreover, do I need to create the Okta application in Tenant B in a specific way to allow SAML assertions ?

Thanks for your help.

Kind regards,